# send user to first page of results when reposting to page?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts, pagination, paged

I have a custom template with a drop-down that filters posts by category. I do it by making the form post to the page itself and then catching the argument and using it in a query (see code below).

Here's the bummer: if you navigate to page 2 (for example) and **then** use the filter, the URL still contains the `/page/2/` bit, and you can sometimes end up with zero posts visible if there are less than a page's worth of results, since the new results all on page 1 and you're stuck on page 2. Tried unsetting the paged variable, to no avail. How can I send the user back to first page every time they use the filter?

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <select id="food-type" name="food_type" class="selectBox">
            <option value="0">Select One:</option>
            <option value="meat">Meat</option>
            <option value="salads">Salads</option>
            <option value="vegetarian-entrees">Vegetarian Entrees</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="search">Search</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I process its contents as follows:

```
global $post;
global $query_string;

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'post_type'        => 'recipe',
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'paged'   => $paged
);

if(isset($_POST['select_food_type']) && !empty($_POST['select_food_type']) ) {
    $args['food_type'] = $_POST['select_food_type'];
    unset($args['paged']);
}
query_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps set your form's action to point to the first page of paged results, rather than the default (empty) of the current page.

```
<form action="_URL_to_first_page_" method="POST">
```

Keep in mind the URL is determined on the client side in the case of an empty action.

Comment: indeed! just got it myself but will mark your answer as correct. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. Make sure the form posts to the proper page every time instead of posting to the current URL.

```
<form action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="POST">
```